# Passing event object in onClick function in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React app in which upon clicking on a column heading, the table sorts the data (via a merge sort).

I want to pass the data (i.e., an array of objects) and the event object. I want to use the event object to get the value of the column clicked, so to then use it to sort the data.

However, I keep getting an error message that the event object is undefined.

Below is the relevant portion of the code:

```
  sortColumn (siteArr, evt) {
    if (siteArr.length < 2) {
      return siteArr;
    } else {
      const column = evt.target.value; // evt returns undefined
      const midPoint = Math.round(siteArr.length / 2);
      const subLeft = this.sortColumn(siteArr.slice(0, midPoint));
      const subRight = this.sortColumn(siteArr.slice(midPoint));
      return this.merge(column, subLeft, subRight); 
    }
  }
  merge (column, left, right) {
    const out = [];
    while (left.length && right.length) {
      out.push(left[0][column] <= right[0][column] ? left.shift() : right.shift());
    }
    while (left.length) {
      out.push(left.shift());
    }
    while (right.length) {
      out.push(right.shift());
    }
    this.setState({sites: out});
    return out;
  }
  render () {
    const siteArr = this.state.sites;
    const sites = this.state.sites.map((site) => {
      return (
          <Site site={site} key={site.id} /> 
        );
    });
    const site_number = sites.length;
    return (
        <div>
          <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th><a onClick={(evt) => this.sortColumn(siteArr, evt)}>Name</a></th>
                <th><a onClick={(evt) => this.sortColumn(siteArr, evt)}>City</a></th>
                <th><a onClick={(evt) => this.sortColumn(siteArr, evt)}>State</a></th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              {sites}
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
    );
  }
```

a) How do I pass the event object to the sortColumn function?

b) How do I access the column value via the event object?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: What are you expecting `event.target.value` to equal? The inner text value like Name or City ?

Comment: Well that's not what `event.target.value` gives you, but it doesn't look like you would need it here because you already have the text value right next to it. why not just `() => this.sortColumn(siteArr, 'Name')`?

Comment: That totally works -- thanks, azium. I guess I'm just not sure how I would access that information from the event object. I figure there must be a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your situation because you already know what the text value is, just pass that to your function:

```
() => this.sortColumn(site‌​Arr, 'Name')
```

However if you want to get the innerText value of the target, that's what you use:

```
event => this.sortColumn(siteArr, event.target.innerText)
```